# What is the result of operator=(std::promise&&) in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I've been reading the C++11 spec, and I'm having trouble understanding the result of one of the `std::promise` object operators (`std::promise& operator=(std::promise&& rhs) noexcept`).

The spec says the effect is "Abandons any shared state and then as if `promise(std::move(rhs)).swap(*this)`."

I get that `*this` will equal the previous value of `rhs`, but what is the effect on `rhs`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`promise& operator=(promise&& rhs)` tranfers the ownership of the `std::promise` from one object to another. After the assigment `rhs`has no associated async result, and `*this` has the one `rhs` had before (if any).